# Add more page numbers in the navigation bar

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to add more page numbers in the bottom of a Wordpress portfolio page. There are currently only 2 numbers; I would like to put 8 pages.

[image: screenshot]

The website is under maintenance and you need to login to see the pages. If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask.

I added parameters:

```
'mid_size'           => 4,
'show_all'           => true,
'end_size'           => 1,
```

in all `$args`, but no effect:

```
$args = array(

                            'post_type'        => 'portfolio',

                            'showposts'        => $items_count,

                            'offset'           => $custom_count,

                            'suppress_filters' => $suppress_filters,

                            'mid_size'           => 4,

                            'show_all'           => true,

                            'end_size'           => 1,

                            );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share the relevant code snippets too.

Comment: I think you have added few portfolios which are showing in two pages only...just add more portfolios, next page will automatically show there..if not solved by this then share your code snippet..

Comment: I added the whole code as they explain it on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: I am not sure about the place to put the argument then I placed everywhere I found the $args but no effect.